# How to encrypt StorageFile in Windows store app (C#/XAML)?

Tags: encryption, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am developing an app which downloads some confidential document. I will download them in `LocalFolder`. But I want to store `StorageFile` in encrypted form, so any geek user can't access those files easily by going to `C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Packages`

I have checks [MSDN samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465017.aspx) about Cryptography, but they doesn't seem quite useful to me. So is there any native WinRT API or 3rd API available, which encrypts the files so it can't be open easily by just "double clicking" on it and when my app request for particular file then the `StorageFile` will be decrypted and it will be displayed in my app.

Comment: I'm building the same feature in my app, have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have not personally used it, but the [DataProtectionProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx) might be worth a look at. The link provides several samples of encrypting data. The samples are not specific to `StorageFile`, but it seems like it should be simple enough to save the results to a file.

Comment: I tried but getting exception, can you please check it ? http://codepaste.net/ayvmx2

Comment: @Xyroid - you are using the wrong constructor for DataProtectionProvider. The one you are using is only for data decryption. For encrypting data, you must use the constructor that has the descriptor string parameter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241562.aspx

Comment: @Xyroid - please read the two doc links above, as the descriptor parameter determines how the data is encrypted.

Comment: can you please guide me how different-different descriptor parameter provide encryption ?

Comment: @Xyroid - unfortunately, no. Like I said, I have not used DataProtectionProvider before.